# Setting a border and a background-color on a radio button (compatible with Firefox, Chrome, Safari)

Tags: html, css

How can I set **borders and background-color** around radio buttons under **Firefox, Safri and Chrome**?

I know it works only with IE.

Below is a capture of IE with RED borders + RED background.

[image]

Below is a capture of Chrome with RED borders + RED background.

[image]

As you can see borders + background are not showed.

Here is my css:

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as this are system objects of a browser its not recommended or even possible to style them via css only. there are many plugins and other solutions outside to fix such problem like my favourite:

use backgroundimages on a div with different classes (selected and unselected) to simulate radio buttons or checkboxes. append/remove input type hiddens dynamically via javascript or jquery if one of this "button" is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
html:

```
<label for="x" class="radio-off">
  <input type="radio" value="example" name="x" id="ex" class="ex">
  label_text
</label>
```

css:

```
    label {
    background:url(img/radio.png") no-repeat;
    }
    input {
    position:relative;
    left:-999em;
    }
label.radio-on {
background-position:0 -10px;
}
```

and simple onclick JS action to change class of label
With this u can customizing your radios and checkboxes as u wish